# Rate limit the messages using Spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration

I am new to Spring-integration.

We have a REST application which is receiving too many messages(6000 messages per minute) than what the database can handle. So I want to rate-limit the requests to 500 messages per 15 seconds (2000 per minute). I was using Queue channel to achieve this.

The application is creating 30,000+ Java threads after sometime. Also, the Queue channel is holding more messages than what is mentioned in the queue capacity.

How to reduce the number of threads and limit the messages in the Queue?

Integration context xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-5.0.xsd">

    <!-- Endpoint -->   
    <int:gateway service-interface="com.ratelimiter.PrintGateway" default-request-channel="inputChannel">
        <int:method name="print"/>  
    </int:gateway>

    <!-- Channel -->
    <int:channel id="inputChannel">
        <int:queue capacity="30000"/>
    </int:channel>

    <!-- Endpoint -->   
    <int:service-activator ref="receiver" input-channel="inputChannel" method="save">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="15" time-unit="SECONDS" max-messages-per-poll="500"></int:poller>
    </int:service-activator>

    <!--  Spring Bean -->
    <bean id="receiver" class="com.ratelimiter.saveToDataStore"/>

</beans>
```

PrintGateway interface:

```
public interface PrintGateway {

    public Future<Message<String>> print(Message<?> message);
}
```

Comment: ...are any of the threads actually running?  30,000 threads sounds like a lot but threads are tiny; if they're running you'd be limited in terms of throughput and performance to however many threads your CPU said it could run concurrently.  But if they're spun up not really doing much...I'm not sure I see a problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since your gateway signature is to return a `Future<Message<String>>`, this is treated as an async gateway: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#async-gateway

By default it uses a

```
private volatile AsyncTaskExecutor asyncExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
```

Which really spins up an new thread for each new message. And what is important: it waits for the reply to fulfill that `Future`. According your code there is not going to be any reply, so, your threads in the gateway wait for nothing for very long time.

You should consider to change the signature of your gateway to the `void` return type. This way you really will send and forget. There are not going to be any background extra threads for nothing.

Comment: Hi, do you know why the messages are stored in queue even when the given queue capacity is exceeded?

Comment: I think the story is about an unlimited `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`, not a `QueueChannel`. Just because without a `send-timeout` on the producer side it is going to stuck forever. You should bring some simple test-case to confirm that you don't see such a behavior on that `<int:channel id="inputChannel">`. I don't understand why don't you follow my recommendation to use a `void` gateway...

Comment: I have used `void` gateway. Now huge number of threads are not being created so I consider that issue to be resolved. The 2nd issue is about the queue capacity. If I give queue capacity as 5 then I expect the 6th messages to be rejected by the queue or throw an exception which was not the case

Comment: You need to configure a `default-request-timeout` on your `PrintGateway` to see a message rejection with the `MessageDeliveryException`. Otherwise your sending thread should be just stuck.